# Can only install one of: magento/page-builder-commerce 1.0.3, 1.0.1?

Tags: magento2.3.2

I am on Magento 2.3.2. I would like to install the new security patch so I ran-

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.2-p2 which gives me this output- 

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Can only install one of: magento/page-builder-commerce[1.0.3, 1.0.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/page-builder-commerce[1.0.3, 1.0.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/page-builder-commerce[1.0.1, 1.0.3].
- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.2-p2 requires magento/page-builder-commerce 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/page-builder-commerce[1.0.3].
- Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.2-p2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.2-p2].
- Installation request for magento/page-builder-commerce (locked at 1.0.1) -> satisfiable by magento/page-builder-commerce[1.0.1].
```

I figured I would try and update pagebuilder.

```
composer update magento/module-page-builder
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
```

I tried adding the version number but that adds more errors-

```
composer require magento/module-page-builder:1.1.0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- magento/module-banner-page-builder 1.0.1 requires magento/module-page-builder 1.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-page-builder[1.0.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- magento/module-banner-page-builder 1.0.1 requires magento/module-page-builder 1.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-page-builder[1.0.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- magento/module-banner-page-builder 1.0.1 requires magento/module-page-builder 1.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-page-builder[1.0.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for magento/module-banner-page-builder (locked at 1.0.1) -> satisfiable by magento/module-banner-page-builder[1.0.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How can I install the security patch?

Answer (score 1):

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition:2.3.2-p2 --no-update
composer require tig/postnl-magento2 --no-update
composer update
```

Is the response I got back from Magento support and it works.I have no idea what postnl is or why it would be required but this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like tig/postnl-magento2 is required by magento/page-builder-commerce. Without the update below, I was not able to upgrade to 2.3.4 from 2.3.2-p2.

```
composer update magento/page-builder-commerce                           
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 4 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing setasign/fpdi (v2.3.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing setasign/fpdf (1.8.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing setasign/fpdi-fpdf (v2.2.0): Downloading (100%)         
  - Installing tig/postnl-magento2 (1.9.1.1): Downloading (100%)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when updating from 2.3.3 to 2.3.3.p1.
Solution provided by tjjen worked for me.

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition:2.3.3-p1 --no-update
composer require tig/postnl-magento2 --no-update
composer update
```

But the module TIG_PostNL was installed and it broke a lot of functionality on the site.

The proper solution we found - using --with-dependencies param:

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition:2.3.3-p1 --no-update
composer update magento/product-enterprise-edition --with-dependencies
```